# Asterisk Call Center Report - Inbound and Outbound Calls

Tags: voip, asterisk, ssrs

We currently use Asterisk to run our call center which handles incoming calls (both direct dial to extension and queues) as well as a bunch of outbound calls. Up until now, we've used a custom report to pull data from the CDR table and report on a user's total phone time. As call center agents, they're expected to have a total phone time of X hours but that can be spread across either type of inbound call, listening to voicemail or outbound calls.

Our custom report works well except for the edge cases that make the CDR messy. For example, a call is answered by one person, transferred into a queue and then not answered by a few agents before one gets it. In this situation, 9 CDR entries are created and the duration is logged on the first, not the person who actually fielded the call.

I've been doing some research and it would be possible to update our custom report but I have a feeling it might be better to use an open source or commercial reporting package that already handles this, and other, edge cases. Does anyone have a recommended package that handles reporting for a high volume call center that deals with both incoming and outbound calls? The ones I've found seem to be designed mostly for incoming queue calls.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check your software or hardware on the user side (softphone or ATA) to use transfer corectly.

It can also can help your asterisk dialplan rewrite.

Best known reporting tool is QueueMetric. You can try the trial and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i recomend you use this https://asterisk-pbx.ru/wiki/soft/call_center/asternic-call-center-stats

its russian regioned but free and very usefull.
need to be php 5.4 + and 7.0 -

iam using it in production now.